# docker-compose + letsencrypt + nginx-proxy. Where is nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, nginx-config, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/blob/master/docs/Docker-Compose.md), and it works as expected. I just want to add an attribute `client_max_body_size 50M` to Nginx, but where to add it in the docker-compose file:

```
nginx-proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  container_name: nginx-proxy
  ports:
  - '80:80'
  - '443:443'
  volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
  - nginx-certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
  - nginx-vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
  - nginx-html:/usr/share/nginx/html
  labels:
  - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true
  restart: always

letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
  image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
  container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
  volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  - nginx-certs:/etc/nginx/certs
  - nginx-vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
  - nginx-html:/usr/share/nginx/html
  restart: always
  depends_on:
  - "nginx-proxy"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a docker file with that configuration and add build config in the docker-compose file.

First, create a Dockerfile named nginx_proxy.df with the following content.

```
FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy
RUN echo "client_max_body_size 50m;" >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom_proxy_settings.conf
```

Then add it to the same location of docker-composer file.

Update your docker-compose file like this.

```
nginx-proxy:
    build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: nginx_proxy.df
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    .............
```